# What is meant by "elementData" and [0] while debugging Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, netbeans, ide

Following are the screenshots while I was debugging. I would like to know what does elementData mean

https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-687ac74cbb37844aaaf5c4ecc96e8623?convert_to_webp=true
 and what does [0] mean. I know its 0th index of elementData array. But what is elementData?

https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-65350d44db817e8e5b4bb102248dd155?convert_to_webp=true

Comment: What would you prefer it be named and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the Data's of your array list and [0]is the 0th element as you only have 1 element currently hence only [0] also size is the size of the array list which is 1

your array list is the element and element data is the data in your array list and under that you see [0] which is the 1st data in your array list element